# Strange bug when launching Android app second time

Tags: java, android

So I am working on a simple android Tetris type game. On the first excecution of the app (from eclipse) everything works just as expected. However if I exit the app and launch it again from the phone this time I see a strange bug. There is a ghost piece that moves down the playing field, but is not actually visible. This piece causes problems because it affects the underlying grid so it takes up space, but is not actually visible. The app will keep generating these ghost pieces as well as the actual pieces the user should be seeing. It seems like the app is not entirely being killed when I exit. Any advice?

Comment: PLease be more specific as to the nature of your problem. If you think the app may not be shutting down properly, then please provide code samples to illustrate the problem. "Ghost pieces" don't really even present an actual problem, just the result of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some static variables.
If you exit and enter again those statics will still hold the old values.

You can check it by calling System.exit(1) in onDestroy just for testing.

Comment: I do have static variables, System.exit(1) fixed the problem! The weird thing is the only static variable is the grid, which is initialized in the constructor. You said I should do this just for testing? What's the correct way to fix this problem?

Comment: make sure all your statics get initialized when you start your game

Comment: The only static variable was being initialized. Hmmm

Answer (score 3):

Have you overridden onPause() to properly clean up the pieces before the game exits?